# Creating an independent draw thread using pthreads (C++)

Tags: c++, pthreads

I'm working on a graphical application which looks something like this:

```
while (Simulator.simulating)
{
    Simulator.update();
    InputManager.processInput();
    VideoManager.draw();
}
```

I do this several times a second, and in the vast majority of cases my computation will be taking up 90 - 99% of my processing time. What I would like to do is take out the processInput and draw functions and have each one run independently.

That way, I can have the input thread always checking for input (at a reasonable rate), and the draw thread attempting to redraw at a given frame rate.

The simulator is already (internally) multithreaded and there is no issues with multiple threads writing to the same data (each one processes a segment).

My issue is I'm not sure how I can properly do this. How would I properly initialize my pthread_t and associated pthread_attr_t so that the thread runs without blocking what I'm doing? In other words, how can I create two threads, each of which run an infinite loop?

To generalize even more, I'm trying to figure out how to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
    pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, func[i], NULL)

for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
    pthread_join(th[i], NULL);
```

Where func[i] is some arbitrary function which runs in an infinite loop doing some arbitrary thing.

Any help or even a link is appreciated, thanks!

Edit: I should mention it is an interactive simulator, so I do need to have two infinite loops running independent of each other. I can only seem to run at once.

Comment: I am not sure that there is enough information in the question for a satisfactory answer.  The issues surrounding designing your threads so that they behave well with each other do not have to do with how the threads are created.  The issues have to do with the methods that are called by each thread and how well concurrency is handled by those methods.

Comment: If the drawing is just dumping the output of the simulator to screen, then there is not much point upgrading the screen faster than Simulator.update() runs. Likewise if the simulator only takes input once per run, there is no point processing input faster than you already are. Do you really need threads here?

Comment: I should have been a bit more specific. It's an interactive simulator with a command input.

Yes, update can happen slower than real time, but the actual application and explore the simulation in 3D while it's still computing the next time step, hence the need for being able to update the screen continuously.

Comment: If that is the actual loop you are running, only one thread will be created because of the `i++` in the `pthread_create` call.  If `threads==2`, this will only create one thread.  Also, the last argument to `pthread_create` is supposed to be a void pointer to anything you want.  Sending in a temporary variable that goes out of scope right after creation of the threads may be problematic.  If you are wanting to pass in the thread number, consider allocating the integer on the heap with `new` or passing the address to a variable that doesn't go out of scope until after the join.

Comment: That i++ in the pthread_create was actually a typo. Thanks for catching that.

If I try doing that above code, I can never get it to work properly. All threads are created, but on join the first one starts excecuting but the rest don't get joined.

Comment: The threads should be running after the pthread_create calls.  The joins should then block execution of the main thread until the child threads exit.  Are you wanting the main thread to continue while the child threads continue to work?

Comment: That clarifies things a bit. I misread something before and I was under the impression that pthread_create only created a new thread, which didn't start executing immediately. I've managed to work out a solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would suggest using [boost::thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/thread.html) as opposed to pthreads since you are using C++.  With `boost::thread` you can do something like this:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void input_thread()
{
    //...
}

void draw_thread()
{
    //...
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread input_th(&input_thread);
    boost::thread draw_th(&draw_thread);

    input_th.join();
    draw_th.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The constructor of a `boost::thread` automatically spawns a new thread and calls the function passed in.  You can also use member functions as threads by using [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bind/bind.html).  The join function blocks until the thread exits.  This is necessary because if `main()` exits, all of your threads are killed.

Hopefully that will get you started, but the hard part is synchronizing (sharing data among threads).  I suggest you look at the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html) for mutexes and condition variables.  Remember that you need to make sure that only one thread is writing to the same memory location at once.  Mutexes help solve this problem.  Condition variables help by allowing you to signal and wait for signals between threads.

For instance, in the input thread you may fill a buffer with input then use a condition variable to signal to the draw thread that input is ready.  In each thread, a mutex should be locked when accessing the buffer so that it is not overwritten by the input thread while the draw thread is trying to read it.  As Goz suggested, a double buffer would make this easier and probably more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll look into this. Thankfully, my problem threads nicely that I only have to split up work between separate threads and never worry about anything being overwritten.

My only reason I was using pthreads was it was what I used previously, and a large portion of my threading code (as well as some legacy code I built off of) already used pthreads. Thank you though!

Comment: Yeah, use what you are comfortable with.  boost::thread actually just thinly wraps the pthread library on any *nix based system, replacing C idioms with C++ idioms (classes, RAII, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

Double buffering is your friend here.  Have 2 buffers of data.  One is the drawing buffer and one is the calculating buffer.  When you have finished calculating then wait for the current draw to finish and then swap the buffers over.  Now it will continue drawing the newly calculated data while you are calculating the next frames worth of data.  Drawing and Simulation are now almost completely de-coupled ...

Comment: Thanks, I already handle double buffering internally. My main issue currently is (essentially) trying to create two separate threads in main() that are both running an infinite loop.